# How to set a minimum range in highstock navigator?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart with it's navigator.
I want to restrict the navigator range and not letting the user to get the range smaller than a year. 
I have a years scale.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I set the property [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval) to one year in milliseconds - 1000*3600*24*356.

Answer (score 0):

You could set [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange) in `xAxis` to one year in milliseconds - `1000*3600*24*356`.